# Replacing original values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `y` which I'm trying to preserve, however is getting replaced by the following operation:

```
ys = np.unique(y)
y2 = y
for i,val in enumerate(ys):
    y2[y2==val]=i
```

Why is the original numpy array getting replaced by this operation? originally the `ys` were 1,5,7 and after the above operation `np.unique(y)` gives: `0,1,2`

Comment: Make a copy `y2 = y.copy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, `y2 = y` simply makes another reference to the underlying numpy array.  As far as python is concerned, `y2` and `y` are indistinguishable.  You can even check `y2 is y` will return `True` and both arrays have the same `id` (memory location).  As noted in the comments, you can make `y2` a *copy* of `y` which does not share the same memory address:

```
y2 = y.copy()
```

Alternatively (and perhaps more efficient), you can rely on builtin numpy functions.  In this case, I think that `numpy.digitize` might suit your needs:

```
np.digitize(y, np.unique(y)) - 1
```

Seems to do the trick.

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 10, 30])
>>> b = np.digitize(a, np.unique(a)) - 1
>>> b
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you do `y2[y2==val]=i` you're manipulating the original array y. Python doesn't copy np array's unless you explicitly tell it to as @John Galt mentioned.
Instead of doing `y2 = y` do `y2 = y.copy()`. This will create a copy of `y` and you'll be manipulating the copy instead of the original.